# Check if Speaker is working programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I want to check if my speaker is working sound or not programmatically.

Currently I was playing audio and recording that and checking if sound is recorded using `peakPower`.

```
recorder?.updateMeters()
let peakRecordedValue: Float = recorder?.peakPower(forChannel: 1) ?? 0.0
if peakRecordedValue <= 0 && peakRecordedValue >= -30 {
    // Speaker is working
}
```

It was working fine for me. But there is a problem. If mic is not working or we have some issue in recording then it will not receive sound and I can't check if this problem is with mic or speaker.

Is there any other way to check if sound is coming from speakers without using other resources like mic.

PS: `AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker` is the current port.

Comment: Play a sound and see if you can hear it via the microphone.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman if microphone is not working. Then how can I test?

Comment: Unless the system itself is able to detect if the microphone or speaker is not working  using some physical sensors (which I don't think it is able to), you cannot determine this programatically without using any sensors (i.e. the microphone), so by using only a single phone, I think you'll only be able to determine if either of the microphone or speaker aren't working, but you won't be able to pinpoint which one of the two is faulty.However, for instance by making the user play sound from another device, you could detect if the microphone is working or not to decide if the speaker is working.

Comment: Why would you want want to do this?

Comment: I can comment on this now, when sound is supposed to be playing but for some reason it's not... the issue is if the mic works, how do you discern from just noise eg.  person talking vs. sound from speaker. (dealing with a webRtc library and sound problems with iPhone currently)